# Dynamic array allocation

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm wondering why new doesn't seem to retain the array information and just returns an int*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*p_to_array)[80];
typedef int arr[80];




int main() 
{
   arr a;
   p_to_array p = &a;  //fine

   p_to_array p2 = new arr; // incompatible types 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That loss of information is called *decay*, and only works in one way.

Comment: Use vectors as they remember their size.

Comment: In recent versions of C++ you can use the `array` container class for fixed size collections.

Answer (score 6):

*I might be totally wrong about this: (i.e. this is little more than an educated guess)*

```
new arr;
```

is equivalent to:

```
new int[80];
```

which by language rules returns `int*`.

---

From cppreference.com: (thanks to @interjay for pointing out I actually cited the irrelevant part)

> The new-expression returns a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, if an array of objects was constructed, a pointer to the initial element of the array.

My understanding of that is that when allocating an array, the `new[]` form will be picked. The only thing your example changes is the syntax; it doesn't make the language treat arrays as non-arrays (regular objects).

Comment: What you quoted from cppreference is about the allocation function (`operator new`), which isn't really relevant because it returns `void*`. The relevant language feature is the [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), specifically: "The new-expression returns a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, if an array of objects was constructed, a pointer to the initial element of the array.".

Comment: @interjay you're of course right. I've changed the quotation to refer to `new` *expression*.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use the array syntax or a typedef-name to allocate arrays with `new` - both is allowed and equivalent according to [expr.new]/5:

> When the allocated object is an array (that is, the
>   *noptr-new-declarator* syntax is used or **the *new-type-id* or *type-id*
>   denotes an array type**), the *new-expression* yields **a pointer to the
>   initial element (if any) of the array**.

As you can see, for arrays, solely a pointer to the initial element is given; Not a pointer to the array object itself. Thus the type yielded is `int*`, not `int (*)[N]`.

The reason why a pointer to the initial element is returned is quite simple: It is the pointer that you want to work with.
We want to write

```
auto p = new int[50];
// Or
int* p = new int[50];
```

So as to be able to use normal subscripting:

```
p[49] = 0xDEADBEEF;
```

That would be nonsensical with `p` if it was of type `int(*)[50]` pointing to the array object, because the subscript would add 49*50*4 to the address, not just 49*4 - because of subscript semantics and pointer arithmetics.
We would have to either use two subscripts:

```
p[0][49] = ...;
```

Which is horrific and unnecessarily redundant. Or we could use a cast:

```
int* p = static_cast<int*>(new int[50]); // Or with auto
```

But that is ugly too.
To avoid such hassles, this rule was introduced.

Comment: Thanks. Source? I don't think it would be nonsensical, the way I stumbled upon this was via [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Memory-mapped_hardware). Instead of casting you'd use double subscripting. This way information gets lost.

Comment: @bla Source for what? `p[49]` would be nonsensical. In fact, it would be presumably UB.

Comment: @bla he said where - `[expr.new]/5`. This refers to a section of C++ Programming Language Standard.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Just thought he referred to an explanation - the Standard doesn't. Might be one of those 'dusty corners'.

Comment: @bla Not really. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Well, so far you're the only one to try to provide an explanation as to 'why'. But as I see it that's no convincing reason for treating initialization with taking the address of a statically allocated array vs. the dynamic case differently.

Comment: You loose pointer arithmetic, not to speak of boundary checking, at least in the context of ownership semantic.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
p_to_array p2 = new arr; // incompatible types
```

type of initializer `new arr;` does not correspond to the type of variable `p2`

The type of initializer is `int *` that is the initializer is pointer to the initial element of the allocated array. The type of variable `p2` is `int (*p_to_array)[80]` according to the typedef definition.

There is no implicit conversion from type `int *` to type `int (*p_to_array)[80]` . So the compiler issues an error.

The correct declaration could look for example the following way

```
p_to_array p2 = new arr[1];
```